# Python Exclude Comments with re.search

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for a string in a line using:

```
import re

myfile = "myfile.txt"
files = open(myfile, 'r').read().splitlines()
for line in file:
    if re.search("`this", line):
        print "bingo"
```

This works fine. However, I want to exclude any lines that are comments. The comments in the file that I am reading the lines from can have comments in the form of `//`. I'm not sure how to exclude the comments though. Comments might start anywhere in the line, not necessarily at the beginning of the line.

Example:

I want to exclude lines like `` first_last = "name" //`this THAT `` since "`this" is in a comment

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312345/regex-to-find-a-string-excluding-comments

Comment: python doesn't support `//` comment

Comment: @AlwaysSunny My script is in python but the file I am reading is not. The file I am reading has comments as I mentioned.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I tested that on a python regex tester but that does not seem to work for python. Throws out errors.

Comment: @sfr You do not need to copy the `regex` as it is because that is written for .net language. Please read [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108542/using-a-net-regex-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a variable length negative lookbehind assertion, but for that you need to use the `regex` package installable with `pip` form the `PyPi` repository. The regex is:

```
(?<!//.*)    # negative lookahead assertion stating that the following must not be preceded by // followed by 0 or more arbitary characters
`this        # matches `this
```

The code:

```
import regex as re

regex = re.compile(r'(?<!//.*)`this')
myfile = "myfile.txt"
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f: # line has newline character at end; call rstrip method on line to get rid if you want
        if regex.search(line):
            print(line, end='')
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xACBvd/1/)